# Zoomed-in AWP Sensitivity

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I notice that the zoomed in AWP have less sensitivity than the normal sensitivity.

**Questions**

1. Is there any way to tune the zoomed-in sensitivity?
2. Is there a way so the zoomed-in sensitivity is always the same with my normal sensitivity?

CVar's please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cl_zoom_sensitivity_ratio`. I believe 1.2 is the default, or at least it used to be in earlier versions of Counter-Strike. You almost definitely don't want the zoomed-in sensitivity to be the same as your normal sensitivity, even if you think you do, but 1.0 will give you a feel that's similar to that.

Comment: So, `zoom_sensitivity_ratio` is the ratio between the normal sensitivity and the zoom sensitivity?

Comment: Fix, The correct command for CSGO is `cl_zoom_sensitivity_ratio`.

Comment: Can you fixed it again? The latest is `zoom_sensitivity_ratio_mouse` for mouse and `zoom_sensitivity_ratio_joystick` for joys. `zoom_sensitivity_ratio` is used befor the 2015 update. Sorry about that.