# What's the default scoped-in mouse speed in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm pretty sure you could have different mouse speed for normal use, and when you are scoped in through a sniper rifle.

What's the default percentage of that?

Comment: [Most sniper rifles divide the field of view/sensitivity by 2.25 on the first zoom, then 6.0 on the second zoom](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/3vxkav/how_zoomed_sensitivity_works/) is that what you are after?  I can't say that that is accurate or not.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yep looks about right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/3vxkav/how_zoomed_sensitivity_works/) that states:

> Most sniper rifles divide the field of view/sensitivity by 2.25 on the first zoom, then 6.0 on the second zoom.

I also found [another post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/3q3cpm/you_are_using_the_wrong_zoom_sensitivity/) saying that:

> If you change "zoom_sensitivity_ratio_mouse 1" to "zoom_sensitivity_ratio_mouse 2.25" you have EXACTLY the same sensitivity scoped or unscoped.

This denotes that the default sensitivity is 2.25 on the first zoom at least.

However, it appears the [AWP has a different default of 1.2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/247925/163757).

Comment: I know this is an older post; but I'm not sure about the "same sensitivity scoped or unscoped".  Based on [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/43urd4/why_0818933027098955175_is_the_best_zoom/) they suggest a pretty random number based on the math and screen orientation (I don't really have the capacity or in-game prowess to verify this).  This has something to do with muscle memory.

Comment: @JMac are you suggesting its random every time you zoom in or its different depending on screen orientation?

Comment: I used "random" poorly there.  I mean it's a really awkward number (they give it to like 15 digits) with a value of ~0.82.